# How to take Screen Shot in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, screenshot

How to take screen Shot in Ubuntu

1. Particular  window screen shot
2. Twin view on only one monitor screen shot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a program 'shutter' which is a fully featured screen shot application. If you don't have it installed then you should be able to get it by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install shutter
```

More simply you will likely have "Take Screeshot" under you Applications—>Accessories menu.

Comment: Unsuprisingly, once they changed the name to "Shutter" from "gscrot" it became a much better program.

Answer (score 11):

Alt + Print Screen will capture the current window.

Comment: This is not working in ubuntu

Comment: really? it works for me. what version are you using?

Comment: Worked for me from Warty to Jaunty and still does.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the Print Screen (Prt Sc) key on your keyboard takes a screen-shot of the entire screen. You can use Alt + Print Screen to take a screen-shot of the currently active Window.

Comment: The most complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

hit the super-key and type "screenshot" (and hit enter)

than it will open a window and select "Grab the current window" to take a screenshot of a window or select "Select area to grab" to select an area.

hit the "Take Screenshot" button

"Grab the current window" take a screenshot from the last selected window
"Select area to grab" to select an area by dragging your mouse (while pressing the left mouse button).
save the file or copy it to your clipboard.